# Static IPv6 addresses have slightly higher latency than dynamic

Tags: networking, ipv6

My apartment assigns public `/64` IPv6 addresses for each client.

I happened to find if I set my IPv6 address static (**`2xxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::2/64`**), it has a higher latency:

```
root@router ~# ip a show eth4
7: eth4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 60:xx:xx:xx:xx:13 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.31.xx.xx/22 brd 172.31.215.255 scope global eth4
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2xxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx::2/64 scope global
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::62xx:xxff:fexx:xx13/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
root@router ~#
root@router ~# ping dns.google -c 5
PING dns.google (2001:4860:4860::8844): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2001:4860:4860::8844: seq=0 ttl=107 time=71.147 ms
64 bytes from 2001:4860:4860::8844: seq=1 ttl=107 time=71.129 ms
64 bytes from 2001:4860:4860::8844: seq=2 ttl=107 time=71.633 ms
64 bytes from 2001:4860:4860::8844: seq=3 ttl=107 time=71.112 ms
64 bytes from 2001:4860:4860::8844: seq=4 ttl=107 time=71.283 ms

--- dns.google ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 71.112/71.260/71.633 ms
```

When I change it to dynamic (**2xxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:62xx:xxff:fexx:xx13/64**):

```
7: eth4: <BROADCAST,MULTICAST,UP,LOWER_UP> mtu 1500 qdisc mq state UP group default qlen 1000
    link/ether 60:xx:xx:xx:xx:13 brd ff:ff:ff:ff:ff:ff
    inet 172.31.xx.xx/22 brd 172.31.215.255 scope global eth4
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 2xxx:xxxx:xxxx:xxxx:62xx:xxff:fexx:xx13/64 scope global
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
    inet6 fe80::62xx:xxff:fexx:xx13/64 scope link
       valid_lft forever preferred_lft forever
root@router ~#
root@router ~# ping dns.google -c 5
PING dns.google (2001:4860:4860::8844): 56 data bytes
64 bytes from 2001:4860:4860::8844: seq=0 ttl=107 time=70.537 ms
64 bytes from 2001:4860:4860::8844: seq=1 ttl=107 time=70.457 ms
64 bytes from 2001:4860:4860::8844: seq=2 ttl=107 time=70.468 ms
64 bytes from 2001:4860:4860::8844: seq=3 ttl=107 time=70.481 ms
64 bytes from 2001:4860:4860::8844: seq=4 ttl=107 time=70.602 ms

--- dns.google ping statistics ---
5 packets transmitted, 5 packets received, 0% packet loss
round-trip min/avg/max = 70.457/70.509/70.602 ms
```

It can reduce the latency for about 1ms.

For some other address (like `240c::6666`) the difference can be 3 - 8 ms.

It doesn't matter at all but I'm just curious that why would this happen.

Comment: Does the same occur if you set the address to `xxx::3` instead? And, can you do a `traceroute --icmp` in both cases?

Comment: Yes, any static address results in the same delay. Tracerouting via both DHCP and Static also gives the same result.

Comment: BTW static IP requires a gateway, and it's currently set as the main router's IP. DHCPv6 uses Link-Local Address (`fe80::xxxx:xxff:fexx:xxxx`) as default gateway, but I changed to it and the delay still exists.